# Moving items between multiple ListBox controls

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, listbox

I have a form where a user can enter the number of students that will be attending a course. Based on how many students will be attending, they are divided into groups. For example, if 80 students will be attending the course and each group has 20 students, there would be 4 groups with 20 students each.

Once the students have been put into groups, each group will be displayed in a `ListBox`. We need to be able to move students from one group (`ListBox`) to another, and the user should be prompted to confirm before a move is committed.

Can someone help to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's a website and your criteria (for the amount of listboxes to be displayed) are entered on the clientside I would solve this using client side javascript.

Or use a `repeater` control based on a textbox that does a postback when the value is changed if you want to do this server side.

Comment: my friend 
1_user search in student by filter i developed before


2_then say search match 100 stu


3_then user enter the nubmer of students in each group


4_so i need alistbox as group contains students and i can move students from one listbox( group) to another listbox and click confirm

Comment: Your question is very vague, how are you 'moving' a student from one listbox to the other?

also, show some code that you already have that might make it more clear

Comment: no code yet this is new module in my project
i mean that as organization cannot give all student course in one time
we devided them to groups user determine it 
if one students cannot attend in first group i can transfer to the second u can figure this case ?

Comment: @thekip: I don't see how this really helps. You've only offered a couple of very vague suggestions, without anything specific to the question at hand...